# jqPagination requests for new page

Tags: jqpagination

I have a large db table that I want to show to users.  I show the info in a table, about 30 rows per page.  I want to use jqPagination to allow the users to jump to a different page.  So page 1 will show rows 1-30, page 2 will show rows 31-60,...  The only example I see are showing how to use it to jump to different section of a page.  Is it possible to use jqPagination in a way to request the next 30 rows to a new page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're displaying all table rows to begin with you could use the following code to only show 30 at a time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // select the table rows
    $table_rows = $('.table-example tbody tr');

    var table_row_limit = 30;

    var page_table = function(page) {

        // calculate the offset and limit values
        var offset = (page - 1) * table_row_limit,
            limit = page * table_row_limit;

        // hide all table rows
        $table_rows.hide();

        // show only the n rows
        $table_rows.slice(offset, limit).show();

    }

    $('.pagination').jqPagination({
        max_page: $table_rows.length / table_row_limit,
        paged: page_table
    });

    // set the initial table state to page 1
    page_table(1);

});
```

[Table pagination example](http://jsbin.com/eviroh/14/edit).

If you don't display all rows to begin with, you could adapt this code to fetch the rows from your system using AJAX instead of showing / hiding.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  If I would have paid more attention to the docs and saw the callback I wouldn't of had to ask a lame question.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3079977 No problem, docs should be improved soon to include some examples.

Comment: @BenEverard : do you have a working example to get pages using php and ajax with jqpagination?